# MySQL Group returns multiple results when aggregate function is equal

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I am trying to obtain a list of results from a database table ('result'), however, each member may have submitted multiple results, and I wish to retrieve their best time.

The query below works (although I'm not sure if it is efficient), except in the case where there are multiple results from the same competitor with the same time scored. (e.g. competitor #2 scores time 32.15 seconds twice). In this situation I get two rows for this competitor, rather than the one I'd like.

```
SELECT result_id FROM ( 
    SELECT member_id,MIN(time) AS mintime FROM result 
        JOIN member_result ON result.id = member_result.result_id 
        WHERE event_id = ? 
        GROUP BY member_id ORDER BY mintime ) AS x 
JOIN result ON result.time = x.mintime
JOIN member_result ON member_result.result_id = result.id
AND member_result.member_id = x.member_id
```

Any suggestions to fix the issue would be greatly received.

EDIT: Structure of tables as requested;

```
member_result (TABLE)
 id int unsigned (10)
 result_id int unsigned (10)
 member_id int unsigned (10)
 club_id int unsigned (10)

result (TABLE)
 id int unsigned (10)
 time decimal (6)
 is50mPool BIT ()
 date date ()
 verified BIT ()
 verified_date timestamp ()
 verified_comment varchar (255)
 hasEmailed BIT ()
 enabled BIT ()
 event_id int unsigned (10
```

sample issue:
result: id#1 for event#2, time 60
member_result: id#1, result_id 1, member_id 3
result: id#2 for event#2, time 60
member_result: id#2, result_id 2, member_id 3

I'd just like one row returned, with either result_id - currently both rows are returned as the min time is equal.

Comment: This is another "least / greatest per group" question. Similar questions have been asked literally hundreds of times before on here - it's probably the most duplicated question on all of StackOverflow. Please use the search feature to find similar questions.

Comment: I did a great deal of searching before posting my question. Indeed, it is a "least/greatest per group" question. However, in the other posts I found, there was no join operation, which here has allowed multiple records to be displayed in my scenario.

Comment: much better if you have included the structure of your tables, sample records and your desired result. MakeUseOf [*SQLFiddle*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: Please provide a schema for `result` and `member_result`.

Comment: edited the above post with these - I'm not quite sure I used SQLFiddle how intended, apologies.

Comment: order by in nested query does not make sense

Comment: I helped you now with the SqlFiddle, next time you can try it like this. It is very usefull. You can find it in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this turned out to be as simple as grouping again on the outer query - something which didn't appear to work initially because of a LIMIT statement I had in place without an ORDER BY before the limit that because of the GROUP BY the query broke.

```
SELECT result_id FROM ( 
SELECT member_id,MIN(time) AS mintime FROM result 
    JOIN member_result ON result.id = member_result.result_id 
    WHERE event_id = ? 
    GROUP BY member_id ORDER BY mintime ) AS x 
JOIN result ON result.time = x.mintime
JOIN member_result ON member_result.result_id = result.id
AND member_result.member_id = x.member_id
GROUP BY member_result.member_id
```

Thanks to all those who contributed!

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

You can try to use MIN or MAX depending on which is more intresting you on the ID, and then there is only one row:

like:

```
SELECT result_id FROM ( 
    SELECT member_id, MIN(member_result.id) as member_resultID ,MIN(time) AS mintime FROM result 
        JOIN member_result ON result.id = member_result.result_id 
        WHERE event_id = 2 
        GROUP BY member_id ORDER BY mintime ) 
AS x 
JOIN result ON result.time = x.mintime
JOIN member_result ON member_result.result_id = result.id
AND member_result.id = x.member_resultID
```

This returns only the MIN time for the given event for the first user. (so only one row instead of two)

and here is an [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89eb2/6) for this.

Comment: while this does fix the problem outlined above, it introduces a new issue where if a competitor has multiple times, but they are not equal, then potentially neither is chosen as MIN(member_result.id) doesn't necessarily pick the ID which matches the minimum time. (e.g. result ID#19 time 1 second, member_result #15 member_id #2, result #24 time 0.01 seconds, member_result #19 member_id #2).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Distinct result_id FROM ( 
SELECT member_id,MIN(time) AS mintime FROM result 
    JOIN member_result ON result.id = member_result.result_id 
    WHERE event_id = ? 
    GROUP BY member_id ) AS x 
JOIN result ON result.time = x.mintime
JOIN member_result ON member_result.result_id = result.id
AND member_result.member_id = x.member_id
```

have you tried this?

Comment: the issue is that I'm having both result_ids returned - in the example given, I'd get both result_id #1 and #2 - so a distinct would not change the output.